# How to synchronize audio and video in FFMPEG/C++

Tags: c++, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm receiving 2 streams (an audio and a video) with timestamps from other PCs in my network.
I'm able to record the video and the audio to separated files (mp4 and aac) with no problems.
Now I'm trying to put the 2 streams together into a mp4 file, I've created 2 queues, one for audio packets and another for video packets and trying to sync them like this:

```
void * muxer(void * param) {
    QPair<AVPacket, unsigned long long int> completePacketAudio;
    QPair<AVPacket, unsigned long long int> completePacketVideo;
    AVPacket pkt;
    int vts = 0;
    int ats = 0;
    while(threadMuxRun) {
        contextMutex.lock(); 
        if(audioPacketQueue.isEmpty() && videoPacketQueue.isEmpty()) {
            contextMutex.unlock();
            Sleep(0);
            continue;
        } else if(audioPacketQueue.isEmpty()) {
            completePacketVideo = videoPacketQueue.head();
            pkt = videoPacketQueue.dequeue().first;
            pkt.pts = vts;
            vts++;
            std::cout << "video ts:" << pkt.pts << std::endl;
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, video_st.st->time_base, video_st.enc->time_base);            
        } else if(videoPacketQueue.isEmpty()) {
            completePacketAudio = audioPacketQueue.head();
            pkt = audioPacketQueue.dequeue().first;
            pkt.pts = ats;
            ats++;
            std::cout << "audio ts:" << pkt.pts << std::endl;
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, audio_st.st->time_base, audio_st.enc->time_base);
        } else {
            completePacketAudio = audioPacketQueue.head();
            completePacketVideo = videoPacketQueue.head();
            if(completePacketVideo.second < completePacketAudio.second) 
            {
                pkt = completePacketVideo.first;
                pkt.pts = vts;
                vts++;
                videoPacketQueue.dequeue();
                std::cout << "video ts:" << pkt.pts << std::endl;
                av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, video_st.st->time_base, video_st.enc->time_base);
            } else {
                audioPacketQueue.dequeue();
                pkt = completePacketAudio.first;
                pkt.pts = ats;
                ats++;
                std::cout << "audio ts:" << pkt.pts << std::endl;
                av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, audio_st.st->time_base, audio_st.enc->time_base);
            }
        }
        av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &pkt);
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
        contextMutex.unlock();

    }

    return NULL;
}
```

my videos is about 10% faster than the audio, and the audio timing is correct (it has 2 minutes when I record for 2 minutes, but the video has just 1:48).

If someone can give a tip, thanks in advance.

Comment: both audio_st.st->time_base and video_st.st->time_base are set in (AVRational) {1, frameRate} with the respective frameRate.